# Why String Builder is returning its length zero, while returning some value of it

Tags: java, java-8, stringbuilder

In below program, String buffer is working as expected, but in case of string builder, the length of String builder is zero, while it's giving me some data. So my question is, if string builder has some value, how can it return its length zero?

```
public class SbVsSbf2 {

    static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    static StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Thread 1
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                sb.append(i);
                sbf.append(i);
            }
        });

        // Thread 2
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
                sb.append(i);
                sbf.append(i);
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println("StringBuilder: " + sb.length());
        System.out.println("StringBuffer: " + sbf.length());
        System.out.println("StringBuilder: " + sb);
        System.out.println("StringBuffer : " + sbf);

    }
}
```

Comment: Because your threads are adding data between printing out the length and printing out the content? Also, `StringBuilder` is not thread-safe, as you probably know.

Comment: `StringBuffer` is thread-safe while `StringBuilder` is not. Also, you are printing the values of `sb` and `sbf` **before** the othr threads have terminated.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand first line. And yeah, I know it is not thread safe, but what is its relevance to length?

Comment: @Abra if threads are not terminated, then why is it not giving its length? I mean how is it related to length? Sorry if it is dumb question, but I am just learning it now.

Comment: You are getting its length, and that length is zero at the moment you're printing it. Content gets added *after* you print the length. Multi-threading at work.

Comment: Fundamentally: if you use a type that isn't thread safe across multiple threads, you shouldn't be surprised when the behavior is hard to understand or predict.

Comment: As said by others, this code is not thread safe, so accessing an object modified by another thread can give you arbitrary inconsistent results. However, in this specific case, it’s (very likely) much simpler. The first string concatenation (`"StringBuilder: " + sb.length()`) is performed when the other threads have not even started their work, so the length predictably is zero. But `println` is a very expensive operation, slowing down the main thread enough, so the other threads make progress. You can change the first line to `System.out.println("StringBuilder: " + sb.length() + " " + sb);`…

Comment: @Holger If I do so, then length is still zero, but this time value is null, may you please explain what that means

Comment: As said, this is the first thing the main thread does after starting the background threads and at this point of time, the background threads have not done anything yet. You get the same result if you replace `StringBuffer` with `StringBuilder`. It’s just a matter of timing. The first execution of `println` takes long enough for the background threads to do something.

Comment: I mean, replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer`, to demonstrate that it doesn’t matter that `StringBuilder` is not thread safe.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, now picture is getting clearer

Comment: I think you could see a difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer if you let t1 and t2 finish (ie call t1.join() and t2.join()). StringBuffer will have all of the characters, with a different order for multiple runs, while StringBuilder will miss characters sometimes. It's pretty rare to miss characters with such small strings getting added though, so the upperlimit of your for loops needs to be higher to see the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly a matter of timing. You can replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer` and get a similar result.

For example, when I run the following program on my machine

```java
public class ThreadStart {
  static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  static long firstAction;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
      Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> firstAction = System.nanoTime());
      long starting = System.nanoTime();
      t1.start();
      int length = sb.length();
      long afterReadingLength = System.nanoTime();
      String s = "StringBuilder: " + length;
      long afterConcatenation = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.println(s);
      long andPrintln = System.nanoTime();
      t1.join();

      System.out.printf("time until %-20s %,d ns%n",
                        "thread's 1st action", firstAction - starting);
      System.out.printf("time until %-20s %,d ns%n",
                        "reading sb.length()", afterReadingLength - starting);
      System.out.printf("time until %-20s %,d ns%n",
                        "string concatenation", afterConcatenation - starting);
      System.out.printf("time until %-20s %,d ns%n",
                        "println completion", andPrintln - starting);
  }
}
```

I get results similar to

```
StringBuilder: 0
time until thread's 1st action  399.000 ns
time until reading sb.length()  181.300 ns
time until string concatenation 195.300 ns
time until println completion   392.800 ns
```

though numbers can vary significantly between runs. It demonstrates the *order of magnitude* of the operations involved.

Starting a thread takes a significant amount of time. That’s one of the reasons  why we use thread pools; handing a task over to an already running worker thread is significantly faster than starting a new thread.

Some of the work has been done within the `start()` method execution in the main thread. I did not try to separate it from the execution of `sb.length()` here, as the time measurement wouldn’t be precise enough. It’s clearly visible that the background thread is far away from doing anything by the time, `sb.length()` returned. Even the string concatenation is not expensive enough.

But after the execution of the first `println` call, we get into the same order of magnitude, so overlapping of the background thread’s activity with the main thread may happen after that.

---

It’s still important to emphasize that you *must not* rely on any assumed timing and changing an object from multiple threads can give you unpredictable results.